Define a function that takes in a string and returns it and every even letter is uppercase, every odd letter is lowercase
def myfunc(mystr):
    placeholderstr = ""

    for item in mystr:
        placeholderstr = item
        if len(placeholderstr) > 1:
            placeholderstr[0::1].lower()
            placeholderstr[1::1].upper()

In the Python code I was hoping to define my function and make the argument into a string and then determine if the string was longer than one character and if it is use the start step and skip to essentially skip to the odd or even number and make it upper or lowercase.

Strings in python are immutable. You just get the value changed to lower and upper as a variable you will never assign and use. -- convert to a list, do the operation and zip the result and join the string -- or create the new string by appending one character at a time

Please show an example to make this clear. For example "Ichiban Fashion" as input (if spaces are allowed - please specify) and the output expected for it.

In your code, there were a few issues. You reassigned placeholderstr to a single character, which caused the loss of the previous string. The check if len(placeholderstr) > 1: was unnecessary, and attempting to modify placeholderstr with placeholderstr[0::1].lower() and placeholderstr[1::1].upper() wouldn't work because strings in Python are immutable.
To resolve this issue, try doing this:
def myfunc(mystr):
    result = ""
    for i, char in enumerate(mystr):
        if i % 2 == 0:  # Check if the index is even
            result += char.upper()  # Convert even-indexed characters to uppercase
        else:  # Index is odd
            result += char.lower()  # Convert odd-indexed characters to lowercase
    return result

